# SQL Query to add result set values as column values

Tags: sql

I want to add the below queries as the column values without creating a table.

```
Select 'NetworkKey' as AuthKey
Select count(NetworkSK) as Totalcount from EDW.Fact.AuthorizationRequest
Select count(*) as NUllcount from EDW.Fact.AuthorizationRequest where NetworkSK is NULL
Select count(*) as NotNullcount from EDW.Fact.AuthorizationRequest where NetworkSK is Not NULL
```

My result should look like this without creating a table physically...

```
AuthKey         Totalcount      Nullcount                      NotNullCount

NetworkKey         100               5                        95
```

Comment: WHY DO YOU HAVE ALL CAPS IN THE TITLE?

Comment: Please be more considerate when posting, ask an actual question and don't post the question as a title. Also don't use all caps for the title. If in doubt read the FAQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **YOU WANT TO DO IT LIKE THIS BECAUSE THIS WILL WORK TO SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM.**

```
SELECT 'NetworkKey' AS AuthKey,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN NetworkSK IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NUllcount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN NetworkSK IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotNullcount
FROM EDW.Fact.AuthorizationRequest
```

Happy holidays.

Comment: I also want to add AuthKey as a first column.. How can I add??

Comment: @Nani - Happy holidays... enjoy.  (hit refresh, I added that column too)

Comment: Thank you genius... Happy holidays :-)

Comment: I also want to add an other row. That starts with 'ClientKey' with other counts.. How can I do that??

Comment: @Nani -- no idea -- I guess it depends on what other counts you want.  I can't read your mind.  I expect it might be easier to understand what I did than then use that as a template for the logic you need.